# AWS Cognito Hosted UI server IP address could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I've been trying to setup my Cognito User pool and the hosted UI sign-in webpage following the documentation from
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html

Followed the steps to the letter, but, it doesn't seem to work when I try to launch the sign-in webpage

> This site can’t be reached
>   {myprefix}.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com’s server IP address could
>   not be found.

I call it from the App integration -> App client settings -> Launch Hosted UI button, so no manipulation of the URL which looks something like `https://{myprefix}.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=<some_client_id>&response_type=code&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin+email+openid+phone+profile&redirect_uri=https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/index.html`

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

OK. So out of a sudden, it's working now as expected. I have no idea how long it takes for the Hosted UI to be deployed and available as I found no information related to this.

Comment: This was true for me as well :)